# What is the default write concern used by PyMongo driver?

Tags: python, mongodb, pymongo

I am trying to use the write concern "ack" for some writes. But Pymongo documentation doesn't say anything about setting this write concern. Is it enforced by some setting on DB servers/replica set? In that case, how can I always use the write concern of "ack" fro some update/inserts?

Answer (score 2):

According to the [documentation](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/release-notes/drivers-write-concern/#write-concern-change-releases), starting from PyMongo 2.4, `ack` is a default write concern.

Quote from the [changelog](http://api.mongodb.org/python/current/changelog.html#changes-in-version-2-4):

> New `MongoClient` and `MongoReplicaSetClient` classes - these connection
>   classes do acknowledged write operations (previously referred to as
>   ‘safe’ writes) by default. `Connection` and `ReplicaSetConnection` are
>   deprecated but still support the old default fire-and-forget behavior.

There is also a related [`write_concern` attribute](http://api.mongodb.org/python/current/api/pymongo/collection.html#pymongo.collection.Collection.write_concern) introduced in 2.4,
which is, starting from 3.0 is a read-only.

Comment: It seems only write concern we can specify is w(write to specific number of relicas), j (journaled) and fsync. Not clear how to use ack write concern instead. http://api.mongodb.org/python/current/api/pymongo/write_concern.html#pymongo.write_concern.WriteConcern

Comment: @NipunTalukdar I haven't personally used any write concerns except the default one, but, I think the [`acknowledged` boolean argument](http://api.mongodb.org/python/current/api/pymongo/write_concern.html#pymongo.write_concern.WriteConcern.acknowledged) controls whether it should be acknowledged or not..